# What's the SQL format for Db2 on IBM Cloud?

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud

I'm using the free version of Db2 on IBM Cloud. I want to use it in Spring Boot application with JDBC driver. But I don't know what's the SQL format for the Db2 on IBM Cloud. The official documents are somewhat clutter. I have googled but can't find a tutorial.

I have the following SQL that works with H2 database. I want to translate to Db2 on IBM Cloud's SQL format. I have searched some SQL dialect translators like this one: https://www.jooq.org/translate/ But it seems not work for the IBM Cloud format.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS id_0065_00000004;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT Exists id_0065_00000004 (
 gmeid           VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
 businessid      VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 businesssubid   VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 kind            VARCHAR(25) ,
 name            VARCHAR(255) ,
 kindvalue       VARCHAR(255) ,
 kindtype        VARCHAR(20) ,
 securitycode    VARCHAR(25) ,
 flowcode        VARCHAR(12) ,
 flowsubcode     VARCHAR(12) ,
 startdate       DATE      NOT NULL,
 enddate         DATE      NOT NULL,
 withdrawaldate  DATE     NOT NULL,
 orientationkey  VARCHAR(500) ,
 parentid        VARCHAR(16) ,
 createdate      DATE,
 createuser      VARCHAR(25) ,
 updatedate      DATE,
 updateuser      VARCHAR(25) ,
 lockflg         BIT,
 lockuser        VARCHAR(25) ,
 lockdate        DATE,
 updatemachine   VARCHAR(25) ,
 PRIMARY KEY (businessid, gmeid, businesssubid)
);

CREATE INDEX kind ON id_0065_00000004(kind);
```

So how do I convert the above SQL to DB2 format?

Comment: What do you mean with 'format'? Do you mean SQL syntax or dialect?

Comment: When you use the free-version of Db2-on-Cloud you don't know in advance which exact version/fixpack of Db2-for-Linux/Unix/Windows you will get.   At present date, It might be Db2 v11.1.3.3b or higher depending on your region/datacentre choices.  The syntax abovein your question would not work with Db2 v11.1, but would work with version 11.5, so omit the "IF EXISTS" and "IF NOT EXISTS" if your database runs on 11.1.x

Comment: And also, recall that all IBM products documentation is at a single place at Knowledge Center (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/).  Particularly syntax for the CREATE TABLE is at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000927.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you exactly mean. [Db2 on Cloud has a download page](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-dr_pkg) for the correct JDBC driver and instructions on how to connect to Db2. Db2 on Cloud is a managed service based on IBM Db2 (for Linux, Windows and UNIX).

Here is a [tutorial for regular Db2 and Spring](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/spring-with-db2-via-jdbc/). Most wrappers support Db2 out of the box.

In the case that you are interested in the actual SQL syntax, there is a link **[SQL Reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFMBX/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/c0004100.html)** on the actual [doc portal for Db2 on Cloud](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-getting-started).

Comment: Oh thanks! I just found the SQL Reference page you linked is not a single page! I had landed on the page but I thought it was just a single page... I just found I need to click menu button to continue read the contents!... Oh, Why they don't set the menu expanded when opening...

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
lockflg         BIT,
```

to

```
lockflg         BOOLEAN,
```

and as @mao points out the IF EXIST and IF NOT EXIST require 11.5