# What is the SQL dialect used in IBM Db2 on Cloud

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-cloud

Does anyone know what is the SQL dialect used in IBM Db2 on Cloud?

I tried googling and also found this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57221628/whats-the-sql-format-for-db2-on-ibm-cloud) but couldn't see any references in the link to what SQL dialect is being used in IBM Db2 on Cloud.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used IBM DB2 on Cloud in the past. What I realized is that they follow most of the SQL standards but as any of the other SQL dialects, they also add a bit of their own flavors. I hope that made sense.

That being said, looks that for the most part, they follow the SQL 2016 standard. Here are a couple of references:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/home/src/cmn/db2z_industrystandardsdb2.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2016

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks @Shogun187. So I guess in some sense IBM DB2 on Cloud has their own slightly different dialect.

Comment: Db2-on-cloud is a DB2-LUW (Linux/Unix/Windows) offering at the present time, broadly in line with SQL-2016. The answer shows a link to Db2-for-Z/OS (which is NOT the flavour of SQL for Db2-on-cloud). A better link is : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.common.doc/doc/c0011215.html . However, there are additional cloud specific syntax as shown in the documentation for Db2-on-cloud https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFMBX/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.kc.doc/welcome.html

Comment: Many thanks @mao. Can I ask is SQL-2016 a dialect on its own? When you mention SQL-2016 is that the same as Microsoft SQL Server 2016. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: @Leockl , please read the links before asking questions. Stackoverflow is not a substitute for education. The wikipedia entry (second link in the answer) will help. Know the difference between an Industry Standard for a language (e.g. ISO/IEC standards for the SQL language), as distinct from an __implementation__ of that standard by a specific vendor( like IBM , or Microsoft) with their specific RDBMS products.

Comment: Thanks @mao, I did see the wiki link but it still wasn’t clear to me. I did say I was new to this. However the last sentence in your last reply above have now made this clear to me

Answer (score 2):

Db2 on Cloud is Db2.

**Db2** is the current name for what has been known as DB2 for Linux Unix and Windows (i.e. DB2 LUW) in the past.

Other varieties of Db2 include **Db2 for z/OS** (i.e. DB2 for OS/390 aka Mainframe) and **Db2 for i** (i.e. DB2 for iSeries aka AS/400) among others

As of version 11.5, **Db2®** conforms with the following SQL standards https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.common.doc/doc/c0011215.html

Db2® conforms with the following industry standards for SQL:

Db2® conforms with the following industry standards for SQL:

> ```
> ISO/IEC 9075-1:2016, Information technology  - Database languages - SQL - Part 1:  Framework (SQL/Framework)
> ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016, Information technology  - Database languages - SQL - Part 2:  Foundation (SQL/Foundation)
> ISO/IEC 9075-3:2016, Information technology  - Database languages - SQL - Part 3:  Call-Level Interface (SQL/CLI)
> ISO/IEC 9075-4:2016, Information technology  - Database languages - SQL - Part 4:  Persistent Stored Modules (SQL/PSM)
> ISO/IEC 9075-10:2016, Information technology - Database languages - SQL - Part 10: Object Language Bindings (SQL/OLB)
> ISO/IEC 9075-11:2016, Information technology - Database languages - SQL - Part 11: Information and Definition Schemas (SQL/Schemata)
> ISO/IEC 9075-13:2016, Information technology - Database languages - SQL - Part 13: Java Routines and Types (SQL/JRT)
> ISO/IEC 9075-14:2016, Information technology - Database languages - SQL - Part 14: XML-Related Specifications (SQL/XML)
> ISO/IEC 13249-3:2011, Information technology - Database languages - SQL multimedia and application packages - Part 3: Spatial
> ```
>
> Db2 conforms with the following industry technical report for SQL:
>
> ```
> ISO/IEC TR 19075-6:2016, Information technology - Database languages - SQL - Part 6: SQL support for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
> ```

Comment: "Update on cascade" is still not supported and it is part of SQL99. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html

Comment: I don't really know how the SQL standard works. I assume there are core things that you need to implement to "conform" and then optional features that some DBMSes will implement but are not mandatory.  Update cascade is part of feature F701 I guess.  A late draft of the 2011 standard available via Wikipedia says e.g.   : "Without Feature F701, “Referential update actions”, conforming SQL language shall not contain an <update rule>."

Comment: If update cascade is important to you, you can raise (or vote) for a DB2 Request for Enhancement

Comment: Table 38 in that draft has "Feature taxonomy and definition for mandatory features" and Table 39 has "Feature taxonomy for optional features".  So I guess that is how you know what the minimum is you need to be able to say product X conforms to the SQL standard.   Of course Db2 will implement a lot of the optional items.. more than most other DBMSes I would suggest.